# "At any moment" vs. "in any moment"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

I am not sure what the differences between these two phrases are. Can you explain when I should use one or the other?

English is not my native language so maybe it is a silly question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*At any moment* is the correct one. Or simply *any moment*.

> The bus will arrive at any moment.
>
> The bus will arrive any moment.

*In a moment* means that something will happen very soon, literally any time within the next moment. This makes *in any moment* senseless.

*At any moment* on the other hand deals with moments as points in time. At any moment will mean, that at any one of this points something will happen. *At a moment* will be senseless, because you don't specify which of the moments you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I think "in any moment" isn't actually correct, for example, of all the cases I could think up, "at any moment" was more appropriate.

"Moment" here refers to "time" not a 'situation', so you can't be 'in' any moment, but "at" any moment.